FastAPI UploadFile on POST interface: random path write
New user of Fast API. I have a common FastAPI POST interface that takes in a user uploaded file:
@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
    ...

Supposely, UploadFile is a temporary file that I could read data from, and closed when this request is done. However, I just learned that if the user specifies a filename in the request, say:
curl -X 'POST' \
    'http://<hostname>/upload/'
    -F 'file=@test.txt;filename=./public/test.txt'

The uploaded test.txt will be written to the location workdir/public/test.txt on my host, where workdir is the working directory that runs my code. This happens before my backend code is run, so even I check the file path and throw http error, the file writing still happened.
It is definitely a security hole and I want to block user option filename here to write file to a random path. What is the best practice in such case? Thank you!


I just learned that if the user specifies a filename in the request...

Where did you learn that? That is certainly not described in the documentation, and I cannot reproduce that behavior using the examples from those docs.
Given this code in app.py:
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    data = file.file.read()
    return {"filename": file.filename, "spool": file.file, "len": len(data)}

I can start the server under the control of strace so that we can see exactly what files it is opening:
strace -o trace -f -s 1024 uvicorn server:app

If I send a file using curl:
$ curl  http://localhost:8000/uploadfile/ -F 'file=@sample.zip;filename=/this/is/a/test.txt'

We can examine the strace logs to verify that FastAPI never uses the filename= parameter to open a local file:
$ grep test.txt trace

This returns only two lines; one is FastAPI reading the HTTP request, and the other is FastAPI sending the JSON response back to the client:
574150 read(15, "--------------------------rZAnyptjm0DIDDjLaui5Pl\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"/this/is/a/test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n...")
574150 writev(15, [{iov_base="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\ndate: Sun, 28 Jul 2024 02:28:20 GMT\r\nserver: uvicorn\r\ncontent-length: 62\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\n\r\n", iov_len=125}, {iov_base="{\"filename\":\"/this/is/a/test.txt\",\"spool\":{},\"len\":2704439758}", iov_len=62}], 2) = 187

Nowhere does it attempt to open a file in the working directory. It does open a temporary as described in the documentation for tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile:
$ grep -E '(open|unlink).*"/tmp' trace
574150 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/qshe1vt7", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = 16
574150 unlink("/tmp/qshe1vt7")          = 0
574150 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp", O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_TMPFILE, 0600) = 16

Note that as described in the documentation, a SpooledTemporaryFile may never open a local file; if a file is smaller than the max_size parameter, it will be stored entirely in memory.

Thank you! But I can repro it on my side. I guess it is a specific config I should look into ...

If you could update your question to include a complete [mcve] I would be happy to take a closer look.
